# regex for words in parenthesis in java

Tags: java, regex

Please suggest me the regex for words which have s in parenthesis

ex: `hello(s)`

I should get `hello` as output

Please suggest me

I have tried these

```
[a-z]\\(s\\)

[a-z]\\(\\s\\)
```

Comment: Hint: you forgot a quantifier

Answer (score 4):

To match the word without the `(s)` that follows it (that is, to match *only* `hello` in `hello(s)`) you can use *positive lookahead*:

```
\\w+(?=\\(s\\))
```

Comment: The only answer that actually shows you read the question atm ("should get hello as output"), `+1`

Comment: @smerny The "output" is undefined without code that produces it. A capture group would usually be enough, if used with `replaceAll`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I would have used a capture group as well, but this works also. The other answers so far have neither and you would have to perform another regex operation or split or substr or something on those (compared to just getting the match or a capture group).

Comment: @smerny `input.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\(s\\)", "$1")`---very simple and straightforward.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, as I said, I would have used capture groups myself. I wonder how you understood my message exactly.

Comment: @smerny Ah, I see, I just parsed it wrong. I applied "on those" to "capture group" instead of "the other answers".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, and after reading OP's comment on another answer... it seems your `replaceAll()` might be what he was looking for which means the question itself is misleading as that makes it seem like he just wants to extract words that prefix `(s)`... either that or the comment was misleading and he is saying he wants to "replace" the result of the match with a different result.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be one or more letters (denoted with a `+`):

```
[a-z]+\\(s\\)
```

To get the string without the `(s)`, you can either use look-ahead or groups.

For groups, the required string must be in brackets:

```
([a-z]+)\\(s\\)
```

And then get the first group, as follows:

```
String str = "hello(s)";
String regex = "([a-z]+)\\(s\\)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches())
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you assume to be a word, the following would work:

```
[a-z]+\\(s\\)
```

This just assumes lowercase English letters as words, and if you usse the case-insensitive flag as well uppercase letters. But `Jörg` or `var_ptr`would not be taken into account.

Comment: `\p{L}` is the best option for the letter character class.

Comment: it is matching hello(s) but how can i replace this word with hello

Comment: In your question, you only asked about matching, not about replacing. But for replacing, use the replaceAll method of String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too

```
 "hello(s)".replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression:

```
(?<=\p{L}+)\(s\)
```

`\p{L}` denote the category of Unicode letters. In ahother hand, you can to use a constant of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\\p{L}+)\\(s\\)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "hello(s), how are you?";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("")
    );  // prints "hello, how are you?"
}
```